# LUFA with pro micro 3.3v 8mhz not working

Tags: serial, arduino-micro, atmega32u4

I am trying to flash my pro micro 3.3v from sparkfun with a Lufa project to make it act as a pokken controller, i am using this project [Github Project](https://github.com/ebith/Switch-Fightstick) I have modified the makefile for 8mhz and set the bootstart pid, this has worked succesfuly on an arduino uno r3, with the same project. When i make the project it works fine then I run `make avrdude`, and it flashes succesfully. the problem though is the pro micro does not show up as a pokken controller as it should. I then tryed it on my switch to no avail. Here is the make file I am using

```
#
#             LUFA Library
#     Copyright (C) Dean Camera, 2014.
#
#  dean [at] fourwalledcubicle [dot] com
#           www.lufa-lib.org
#
# --------------------------------------
#         LUFA Project Makefile.
# --------------------------------------

# Run "make help" for target help.
PID          = 0x9203
BOOT_START   = 0x9203
ARDUINO_MODEL_PID = 0x9203
MCU          = atmega32u4
ARCH         = AVR8
F_CPU        = 8000000
F_USB        = $(F_CPU)
OPTIMIZATION = s
TARGET       = Joystick
SRC          = $(TARGET).c Descriptors.c $(LUFA_SRC_USB) $(LUFA_SRC_SERIAL)
LUFA_PATH    = ./lufa/LUFA
CC_FLAGS     = -DUSE_LUFA_CONFIG_HEADER -IConfig/
LD_FLAGS     =
AVRDUDE_PROGRAMMER = avr109 # Add this
AVRDUDE_PORT = COM5 # And this too (use your correct COM port)
MCU_AVRDUDE = atmega32u4
MCU_DFU = atmega32u4

# Default target
all:

# Include LUFA build script makefiles
include $(LUFA_PATH)/Build/lufa_core.mk
include $(LUFA_PATH)/Build/lufa_sources.mk
include $(LUFA_PATH)/Build/lufa_build.mk
include $(LUFA_PATH)/Build/lufa_cppcheck.mk
include $(LUFA_PATH)/Build/lufa_doxygen.mk
include $(LUFA_PATH)/Build/lufa_dfu.mk
include $(LUFA_PATH)/Build/lufa_hid.mk
include $(LUFA_PATH)/Build/lufa_avrdude.mk
include $(LUFA_PATH)/Build/lufa_atprogram.mk
```

Any Help would be appreciated

Comment: go back to the beginning ... configure the arduino as a usb keyboard ... that will confirm that your hardware and software works